# Bass trombone maintenance

Tags: bass-trombone, instrument-maintenance

I have just purchased a Jupiter 1240 L-T bass trombone which has Thayer Valves.  I am wondering if:

1. It is possible to wash the instrument in the bath tub (will the Thayer Valves be ruined?)
2. Can I use rotor oil on the Thayer Valves?

Answer (score 1):

You should disassemble the trombone before washing it in the bathtub. In particular, you don't want mold or food particles getting caught in the valve (as gross as that sounds, it happens). Yes, you can use rotor oil on the valves.